# vue-meta => How to change the header information

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a nuxtjs project with a page opening on a url like `server\posts\id`. On this page I have added `head` information to influence the meta tags. However, some tags are post specific and need to be filled dynamically. This only seems possible after you have data loaded in `mounted`. How can I add the meta maniplulation to `mounted`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need an extra 'data' property. If you use this in the header, and update it later it will change the meta information.

Answer (score 0):

Right way to get meta from api is: using fetch method

```
  async fetch({ store, params }) {
    await store.dispatch('modules/item/get_item', params.article)
  },
```

Use Computed :

```
  computed: {
    ...mapState('modules/item', {
      Item: (state) => state.data
    })
  },
```

and use nuxt head (vue-meta)

```
head() {
    return {
      title:
        this.$store.state.modules.general.info.name + ' / ' + this.Item.title,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content:
            this.$store.state.modules.general.info.name +
            ' / ' +
            this.Item.seo_description
        },
  }
```